# convert instant to LocalDate and got java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year

Tags: java, junit, java-time, localdate, java.time.instant

I converted an instant to LocalDate and here is my implementation:

```
theInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

However, I got the exception in Junit test:
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -1000000000

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you create the `Instant`? Would be good to see the JUnit test here, too... And in addition, you have converted the `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime` by `.atZone(...)` and then extracted the date part by `.toLocalDate()`.

Comment: This kind of reproduces the error `Instant.MIN.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());`

Comment: atZone method description says `An exception will be thrown if the instant is toolarge to fit into a zoned date-time.`

Comment: Help us to help you. What does `theInstant` contain?

Comment: Also what sense does it make to have an instant that is 1000 million years ago?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for whatever instant you provided it must be in the range of `-999999999 to 999999999` where `0` is the epoch. You can create an instant several ways.  One is to specify the current date.

```
LocalDate ld = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();      
System.out.println(ld);
```

prints

```
2021-03-05
```

Another is to give it a value in some unit of time.  Here is one for seconds.

```
    LocalDate ld = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1229998889L)
           .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Prints

```
2008-12-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `LocatDate`

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();  //local date

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atTime(10, 45, 56);  //Add time information

    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"); // Zone information you can present ZoneId.systemDefault() here

    ZonedDateTime zdtAtAsia = localDateTime.atZone(zoneId); // add zone information

    ZonedDateTime zdtAtET = zdtAtAsia
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")); // Same time in ET timezone
```

thats all!